# Should I use 1 or 2 models in Mongoose for scalability and good practice reasons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using (MongoDb) mongoose to store data for a making a educational platform, and I have two models: teachers and students, both of them share most of the fields, so the question I have is, for scalability and good practice reasons. Should I use 1 or 2 models in Mongoose for scalability and good practice reasons?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a true expert in databases, but I think the models are really similar, and you're sure that you won't be adding new stuff to the models, you can just do it in one model, but it's much better in my opinion to have separate models for students and for teachers, because students don't have a lot of things in common with teachers, so if for example, you want to add a `grade` parameter to the students, well it also gets added to teachers which doesn't make any sense.